# Is it possible to get an inescapable question ban?

Tags: discussion

On Stack Overflow, I have been question banned, and it seems nearly impossible to get unbanned. A moderator keeps deleting my downvoted questions...

Comment: You should post this on [Meta.StackOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). Why here?

Comment: This question isn't specific to Stack Overflow, it can be applied to all stack exchange sites.

Comment: Then state that in your question, otherwise it seems like it may be specific to one site.

Comment: You have posted something similar on Meta SO http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294020/judging-from-my-stack-overflow-profile-when-will-i-get-to-ask-questions-again

Comment: -1 because you make it sound like a personal hunt, which I'm more than sure that it isn't. Anyway there is a faq question just for this, not site specific.

Comment: How do I fly without eating metal?

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: No.

Slightly longer answer: It is always possible to get out of a quality block (the umbrella term for the "question ban" and its sibling the "answer ban") as long as you are willing to put in enough time and effort. All the information you need is in [the FAQ entry Makoto linked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). If enough of your posts are deleted, you may need help from a moderator to get your posts undeleted so that you can improve them.